Firebase: Error (auth argument-error) - React
Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).
import { getAuth, RecaptchaVerifier, signInWithPhoneNumber } from 'firebase/auth';
import { firebaseConfig } from '../Global/firebaseConfig';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

 const setupRecaptcha = () => {
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    auth.settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = true;
 
    // @ts-ignore
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
      'size': 'invisible',
      'callback': (response: any) => {
        // reCAPTCHA solved
      }
    }, auth);
  };

  const sendVerificationCode = () => {
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    auth.settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = true;
    // @ts-ignore
    const appVerifier = window?.recaptchaVerifier;
    signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, sendTo, appVerifier)
      .then((confirmationResult) => {
        setConfirmationResult(confirmationResult);
      }).catch((error) => {
        setError("Error sending SMS: " + error.message);
      });
  };

  const verifyOtpSubmit = async () => {
    if (confirmationResult) {
      confirmationResult.confirm(otp)
        .then((result: any) => {
          const user = result.user;
          setVerified(true);
        }).catch((error: any) => {
          setError("Error verifying code: " + error.message);
        });
    }
  };

<div id="recaptcha-container"></div>

"firebase": "^9.23.0",


I tried changing versions but nothing is working. but i keep getting same error, through console.log i can see that issue is with recaptchaVerifier
Here is a look on console.logs error, which shows error on RecaptchaVerifier

assert.ts:136 Uncaught 
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).
    at createErrorInternal (assert.ts:136:1)
    at _assert (assert.ts:167:1)
    at new RecaptchaVerifier (recaptcha_verifier.ts:107:1)
    at setupRecaptcha (TwoFactorConfirmation.tsx:51:1)
    at TwoFactorConfirmation.tsx:36:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23189:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24965:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24930:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24917:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24905:1)





Which line of code causes the error?  If it's signInWithPhoneNumber, then you need to make sure the arguments are correct.  You're not showing us the value of sendTo.  Please edit the question to be more clear.

Also, you only need to call initializeApp once when the page loads.  There is no value in calling it multiples times (unless for some reason you are trying to intialize multiple apps).

@DougStevenson sendTo value is valid phone number. Error has nothing to do with signInWithPhoneNumber. instead it shows on
window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
'size': 'invisible',
'callback': (response: any) => {
// reCAPTCHA solved
}
}, auth);

Yes i tried initializeApp with once earlier but error still persist

@DougStevenson i have also added console image

Please copy the error message into the question instead of showing an image.  Also you should make it clear in your question which line of code is causing the problem.

Done. I have mentioned there @DougStevenson

According to the example in the documentation, the first argument to the RecaptchaVerifier constructor is an Auth object, which you are missing:
const auth = getAuth();
window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth, 'recaptcha-container', {});

You can also see the API documentation for the RecaptchaVerifier constructor.

now the error is Cannot create property 'callback' on string 'recaptcha-container'. I am using version 9.x i guess what you are saying is 10 and above

If you are bound to a specific version of an SDK, you need to make that clear in your question so others know what to expect.  If you have a new problem entirely, please post it separately along with your new debugging details.  We can't go back and forth in comments indefinitely.

I guess i have mentioned the my version in question. Secondly its still same issue, so please if you cant help our let others help
